# Correct way to write a Modifier factory function

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following method which sets the width of something in a LazyItemScope to 300.dp if the screen width is 600.dp or more or 80% of the width is smaller.

```
@Composable
private fun LazyItemScope.widthModifier(configuration: Configuration = LocalConfiguration.current): Modifier =
    if (configuration.screenWidthDp >= 600) Modifier.width(300.dp) else Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth(.8f)
```

This gives a warning that Modifier factory functions should used composed so I rewrote it as follows:

```
private fun LazyItemScope.widthModifier(): Modifier =
    Modifier.composed {
        val configuration: Configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
        if (configuration.screenWidthDp >= 600) Modifier.width(300.dp) else Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth(.8f)
    }
```

But I still get an error message stating that Modifier extension functions should be extensions on Modifier. But if it is an extension on Modifier then `fillParentMaxWidth` is not available.

Is there any way I can rewrite this to make it compliant with the lint checks?

Answer (score 2):

You can either suppress lint warning as

```
@SuppressLint("ModifierFactoryExtensionFunction")
private fun LazyItemScope.widthModifier(): Modifier =
    Modifier.composed {
        val configuration: Configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
        if (configuration.screenWidthDp >= 600) Modifier.width(300.dp) else Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth(.8f)
    }
```

and use it inside LazyItemScope as

```
LazyColumn() {
    items(100){
        this.widthModifier()
    }
}
```

or pass alternative modifier as parameter to Modifier extension function as

```
private fun Modifier.widthModifier2(modifier: Modifier): Modifier = composed {
        val configuration: Configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
        if (configuration.screenWidthDp >= 600) Modifier.width(300.dp) else modifier
    }
```

And use as

```
LazyColumn() {
    items(100) {
        Modifier.widthModifier2(Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth(.8f))
    }
}
```